# How can I access the child of a unique key in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to access the child value of a unique key value (that had been "pushed") within Firebase. Currently, my database looks like this: [image]      I want to access the value of "emailOfUser"

I am very new to Firebase so I am not familiar with the functions. Currently, this is my method of obtaining other values for a different section of the database: [image]

Thank you so much for any feedback!

I've tried different methods to accessing this data within the Firebase, but I cannot get it to work/the methods I were using were outdated. I also tried to "update" the Firebase instead of "pushing" the values to prevent a unique key from generating, but it simply overwrote my current data rather than appending something new.

Comment: Assuming there can be multiple nodes in usersWhoVoted, do you want to fetch emailOfUser of all nodes or just any specific ones? Also what is the desired DB structure that you are trying to create instead of the random push keys.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- For sharing the database structure: You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load all the users who voted and print their emails, you can do that with:

```
get(child(dbref, 'usersWhoVoted')).then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    console.log(childSnapshot.key, childSnapshot.val().emailOfUser);
  });
})
```

---

Note that your current structure allows a user to vote multiple times. If you want to only allow them to vote once, use some identifier of the user as the key in your database structure:

```
userVotes: {
  "uniqueIdOfUser1": "valueTheyVotedOn",
  "uniqueIdOfUser1": "valueTheyVotedOn",
  ...
}
```

Now each user can by definition only vote once, If they vote again (assuming your security rules allow that), their new vote will simply replace the existing vote.